# Deploying Blazor WASM with caching dependencies

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, http-caching

I'm trying to deploy my AOT-compiled Blazor WASM app as static resources served by a normal Asp.NET server.
This works. but I'm facing two issues with this.

1. The output seems unreasonably large. e.g `_framework/dotnet.wasm` is a whopping 87mB.
   Is this expected?
2. `_framework/dotnet.wasm` is not cached in the browser, resulting in a full download each visit/refresh.

I have configured the server to serve static content with cache headers set.
I can see the cache headers on the request in the browser.

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 48154724
Content-Type: application/wasm
Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2023 18:34:58 GMT
ETag: "1d92a9280cc0c64"
Last-Modified: Tue, 17 Jan 2023 16:41:12 GMT
```

The static file settings looks like so:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true, //serve the framework files

    HttpsCompression = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.HttpsCompressionMode.Compress,
    OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
    {
        var headers = context.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
        headers.CacheControl = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(30)
        };
    }
});
```

For the Blazor WASM site, the following settings are used:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <RootNamespace>TraceLens.Site</RootNamespace>
        <RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
        <BlazorCacheBootResources>true</BlazorCacheBootResources>
        <BlazorEnableCompression>true</BlazorEnableCompression>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

TLDR:

dotnet.wasm is 87 MB, it takes 12 seconds to download, and it's not cached.
Any pointers are very welcome.
I'm not sure where to begin or what to ask here

The actual site can be found here: (it does start after the 12ish seconds)

http://traceview.ornell.io/logs?traceId=629FA6A4B6873921F600F59DFD0A4539&search=

Comment: `dotnet.wasm` should be about 2.5 MB uncompressed. 1 MB when served gzipped by ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Although with AOT compilation, like you're using, it will get significantly larger, but I don't think it would be at 90 MB.

Comment: Enabling Trimming got it down to 38mb. but it is still just as slow to load. if I disable AOT compilation. it all works very nicely. ~1 sec load time and no weird filesize.
(which I currently use on the live site now)
But I would still very much like to be able to use AOT